# JavaScript WebService NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services, cors

I've got some really simple javascript code with two buttons. The first submits a form that calls a web service function and opens this in a new window.

The second button is supposed to do the same thing except that I want to put the response text from the web service into a div on the page.

The web service came from an example I found [here](http://encosia.com/using-cors-to-access-asp-net-services-across-domains/) (*you can download the project in a zip file at the bottom.*)

- There was a typo in the WebService.asmx markup where the Class attribute should be "Encosia.Samples.ASMX_CORS.WebService".

The web service has allowed all origins `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />` so there shouldn't be a problem with cross-site scripting.

**JavaScript code** (*note: the local host name was generated by Visual Studio when I run the web service project*)

```
<head>
   <title>Test Web Service Using JavaScript</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action='http://localhost:53276/WebService.asmx/HelloWorld' method="post" target="_blank">
        <input type="submit" value="This Works" class="button">
        <label> This opens a new window with the result of the web service call</label>
    </form>

    <input type='submit' id='btnTest' name='btnTest' value="This Doesn't" onclick="WebRequestTest();" >
    <label> This should fill the div with the result of the web service call</label>
     <div id="MyDiv"></div>


</body></html>

<script language="javascript">

    function WebRequestTest() {
        function handler() {
            //fires when ready state changes
            if (this.readyState == 4 ){ //&& request.responseText != '') {
                var response = request.responseText;
                document.getElementById('MyDiv').innerHTML = response;
                return;
            } 
        }

        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onreadystatechange = handler;
        request.withCredentials = true;
        request.open('POST', 'http://localhost:53276/WebService.asmx/HelloWorld', true); //third optional argument: async (default true)
        request.send();
    }

</script>
```

When I click the first button a new page opens showing the XML result of the `XMLHttpRequest`. When I click the second button HttpFox tells me I have an:

> NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI error

the result is just an empty string.

I've also tried `jQuery` thusly with the same result:

```
function WebRequestTest2(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:53276/WebService.asmx/HelloWorld",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            var myString = $(xml).find('string').text();
    }
    });
}
```

To add further insult to injury, the JavaScript code above works fine in IE 8, but not Firefox 17 which is my target browser.

Can anyone tell me how to make Firefox play nice with my web service? It's been suggested to me that I may need a CORS library in my web service, but it seems like a problem this common must have an already defined solution built in.

Comment: Is this suppose to be a `POST` or `GET`? What is the mime-type of the response?

Comment: Ideally POST, but I haven't been able to get either one to work so far. The data type should be application/x-www-form-urlencoded, which I believe is the default, right?

EDIT: The response should return a string such as `<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">Hello World</string>`

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my issue by using the WebAPI CORS functionality following this example: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Additionally, I needed to override the origin sent by firefox as it is null when loading files locally. I used HttpFox to do this.